# How is it that Email Marketing Platforms like mailchimp are able send emails from me without me giving them my email password?

Tags: email, gmail, smtp, spam-prevention, spoofing

Mail Chimp, SendinBlue, and etc are email marketing platforms that can do email blasting. I noticed that they are able to send an email and mark it as 'From' my email. Its very weird to me as i never gave them my email password nor the details of my smtp server.

How are they doing this?

And how does mail servers like gmail know that they are not spoofing?

Comment: They are not sent from **your** SMTP server. They have their own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of these services need you to authenticate your email domain.
The process includes updating DNS records to add information that allows their servers to send mail from your address without being marked as spam.

Depending on the service they may add their server information to your SPF record, create a DMARC key, and/or add CNAME records that point to them.

Since you mentioned Mailchimp, here is a link to their help page explaining the process.
https://mailchimp.com/help/set-up-custom-domain-authentication-dkim-and-spf/

Without doing these types of things the best they should be able to do is send-on-behalf.
Which will still show your name but may also add a "on behalf of" or "via" added.

Comment: I never did the extra steps for mailchimp. I just signed up to their service. So they are definitely sending on behalf. This baffles me cause the email did not go to spam. Fyi I'm using gmail

Comment: Mailchimp has a process to help with this kind of thing.
With free accounts such as Gmail, the necessary authorizations can't be done, because you don't own the domain.
They do have a system in place to help avoid failing spam checks.
Basically, they change the sending address to add their domain at the end.
Here's a link to their help page on the subject.
https://mailchimp.com/help/limitations-of-free-email-addresses/